# K&R C Programming book, section 4.3 reverse Polish calculator example

Tags: c

When I read 4.3 part of the book, which is to write a simple calculator called reverse Polish calculator,
I'm a little confused about this paragraph:
[image]

[image]

when the input like:

[image]

Do we really care about the the problem of reading too much?
If someone can illustrate an example to show it's necessary to have ungetch method, that's must be great!

Comment: Think of a skip white space function. You would read until something else comes along. Then the read character is put back in the input stream.

Comment: Tokens in this example need not be whitespace-separated, so for example: `1 2+` If you require tokens to be whitespace-separated, this is still an example because it should be an error.

Comment: Dont use screenshots for code.

Comment: @Devolus, I will type code next time, thx for mentioning!

Comment: @Paul Hankin, you are right! thx for this example, my example is just too simple and perfectly skipped a lot of circumstances!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is

```
1 2 -
```

In this case `getch()` will return these characters in sequence:

- `'1'`
- `' '`
- `'2'`
- `' '`
- `'-'`
- `'\n'`

This is simple, as each number consists of just one character, and your program could simply assume that it does not need to read more, or finish the reading of a number on a blank.

But if your input is

```
23 314+11*42/
```

How would your same program know when a number is complete?

Well, it needs to read the character after the last digit. And because this next character might be important for the following operation, it needs to be "pushed back" into the input. This is what `ungetch()` does.

For example, after collecting `'3'`, `'1'`, and `'4'`, it needs to read `'+'` to find that the number was complete with `'4'`. But the `'+'` must be preserved for the next call of `getop()` to return `'+'`.

Comment: thx a lot!, suddenly I realized that it is absolutely necessary, my example is simple as you said so it does NOT affect the result, but with your example, it cleared my confusion!